# Need Script changed to a different page in the same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, vlookup

I have a script on a sheet in my Google Sheets workbook that emails when a cell changes to "TRUE", but the cells in question are a vlookup to another sheet in the workbook.

This works in the "MASTER" tab in the workbook but I need to change it to the "Outbound Parts" tab, or be able to change the script to read what the Vlookup is bringing back.  I'm new at this and I'm struggling to find how to make this work, any ideas would help.

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
  if (e.range.columnStart != 8 || e.value != "TRUE") return;
  const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,7).getValues();
  let ShippingFrom = rData[0][1];
  let ShippingTo = rData[0][2];
  let PO = rData[0][3];
  let Supplier = rData[0][4];
  let Part = rData[0][5];
  
  let msg = "Order number " + PO + " into " + ShippingFrom + " going to " + ShippingTo + " containing " + Part + " from " + Supplier + " ready for interbranch. ";
  Logger.log(msg);
  GmailApp.sendEmail("jyearous@gmail.com", "Parts Received", msg)
}
```

Comment: Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. Clearly indicate which data you want to include in the email.

Comment: Sorry about that, link below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XwZxCUfFxPDMU6pKJaDAGxhUnjdUW9hRW4Ll3t7fXBw/edit?usp=sharing

I am wanting the Email to be titled "Parts Received" and the body of the email to be:

Order number 4164 into LANS going to MTPLE containing 6223 from BE ready for interbranch.

I want to be able to check the received box on "Outbound Parts" tab and send the email, but the script that I built is running on the "MASTER" tab.  I did not think about the vlookup not actually changing what the cell said, just what appeared.

Comment: It is unclear why want to click on one sheet but get the data from another. It should be doable, and I am giving a solution outline below, but please clarify why you are building a workflow like that.

Comment: It doesn't need to read off of the "Master" tab.  I had originally set it up so that user A could use the "Master" tab and User B would be in the store, letting user A know that the parts had been received, and clicking the button that they were able to edit on "Outbound Parts"  But then, with the vlookup, I realized that the corresponding cell in "Master" wasn't changing to "TRUE" so I wanted to change the trigger from the "Master" tab to the "Outbound Parts" tab, but I don't know where in the code that was specified.  I don't need to build the workflow that way, I am just new and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to run on an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `on edit` trigger. When you click a checkbox to run the code, the active sheet will be the one where you click, i.e., `Outbound Parts`.

You are saying that you want the code to use data from another sheet, i.e.,  `Master`. One way to do that would be to use [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to get the `Master` sheet, and find the correct row by using `Array.indexOf()` with the value in column `A` in the active sheet as search key, and the values in `Master!J2:J` as the array. You can get those values with something like `const keys = e.source.getRange('Master!J2:J).getValues().flat()`.

You can then fill the email message with data from the row you located.

Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Beginner's Guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/), the [New Apps Script Editor guide](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-ide/), the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).